# TypeError document.querySelector(...) is null

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a FF extension and I hit a snag. Here's what I have:

```
var canLink = document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]').href;
```

This finds a link with rel="service" and it works great. However, if the page does not have a link with rel=service, it returns null and breaks out of the rest of the program. How can I make it so that if canLink = null, it doesn't break?

Is there a way to catch this error?

Here is the file. Line 12 is self.port.emit, which works fine.

```
//Get link if it exists
var elem = document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]').href,
canLink = elem ? elem.href : "";

if (canLink){
    self.port.emit("link", canLink);
}

else {
        canLink = "";
        self.port.emit("link", canLink);
}
```

Comment: Check that you have an element before you work with it.

Comment: `var canLink = (document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]') || {href: ""}).href;`

Comment: Can you do make cfx on this and upload the xpi onto github and share

Comment: I got it working! I will put a version of it on github when I get the chance.

Comment: Per the answer by @AmitJoki, the line `var elem = document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]').href,` should be `var elem = document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]'),`.  The issue is that you are attempting to access a property of a `null` value (`null.href`).  The point of the change that was in that answer was to check for a `null` or `undefined` value prior to attempting to access the property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a simple condition

```
var elem = document.querySelector('link[rel="service"]');
var canLink = elem ? elem.href : "";
```

Now in your code you could check in your code for `""` (empty string) and take further measures like

```
if(canLink !== "") {  // could be just written as if(canLink){ ... }
   // do something with the canLink now
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added that, but the error persists. Here is the error: console.error: canon-check:
  Message: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
  Stack:
    @resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/users/yunk/
appdata/local/temp/tmpsut7oh.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-iQY7ATsRGQ7q3w@jetpack.xp
i!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource
://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://jid1-iqy7atsrgq7q3w-
at-jetpack/canon-check/data/getHTML.js:2:12

Comment: @JasePellerin then the error isn't on that line.. it is somewhere else in the code which you've not shown

Comment: Yeah, the line it's referencing doesn't make sense though. I'll post the whole file contents below.

Comment: @JasePellerin i have a feeling that the `document` variable is not what you expect, I'm thinking whatever `document` is it doesnt have `querySelector` so make sure that `document` is really the document.