# document.querySelector works in console but not on realtime

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm creating a simple html page with one audio player inside an iframe.
I need to enable kind of autoplay for desktop and mobile.

The player is this one:

```
<div style="width: 100%"><iframe src="https://players.rcast.net/fixedbar1/66549" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" autoplay style="width: 100%"></iframe></div>
```

I put this block on the bottom of the html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
        // this function runs when the DOM is ready
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector('.play-btn').click();
        },3000); //delay is in milliseconds 

    });

</script>
```

Using firefox console `document.querySelector('.play-btn').click();` works fine, but on runtime i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
```

Any ideas or best ways?

Thanks,
Red

Comment: Are you trying to querySelect a button that is inside the iframe?

Comment: Please try to add an id to iframe element and then use that id to trigger the play button click: <div style="width: 100%"><iframe id="myiframe" src="https://players.rcast.net/fixedbar1/66549" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" autoplay style="width: 100%"></iframe></div> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
      
        setTimeout(function(){       document.querySelector('#myiframe .play-btn').click();
        },3000); 
    });
</script>

Comment: @JakeAve yes is it, is inside the iframe

Comment: I don't think this is possible for two reasons 1) You [can't access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9393532/15273968) iframe contents from other domain. 2) Browsers [don't allow audio autoplay](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) before certain conditions are met, certainly not on document onload.

Comment: @RedVelvet, please, view this topic: [Trigger a button click inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332339/trigger-a-button-click-inside-an-iframe). I think this will answer your question.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want in the console but you would only be able to access iframe content programmatically if your iframe domain matches your current domain.

That being said, you can:

Select the iframe, then run  query selector on the iframe (you don't even need jQuery for it):

```
const iframeElement = document.querySelector('iframe'); 
iframeElement.querySelector('.play-btn').click();
```

*Tips:*

1. You can also play the video/music directly by calling `play()` on
   the media elements. So you can cut out stimulating click on
   the button.
2. `querySelector` is slower than `getElementById`, you can assign an `id` attribute to your iframe/button/media element and find it directly.

   It will also help you avoid bugs because `querySelector` returns the first match. So in case you have multiple `iframe` or multiple elements with the class `.play-btn`, it can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you should select iframe at first and get its content window to access all elements on it.

```
const myIframe = document.querySelector('#iframe_id')
const myIframeDocument =myIframe.contentWindow.document
const myElement = myIframeDocument.body.querySelector('#target_element')
```

it is noticeable that the iframe should be loaded completely before your process and also domain conflict

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
   <iframe id="video1" width="450" height="280" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJ2X4dFhAC0?enablejsapi" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<a href="#" id="playvideo">Play button</a>
<script>
 $("#playvideo").click(function(){
  $("#video1")[0].src += "?autoplay=1";
 });
</script>
```

I found this on [Grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/autoplay+1+video+iframe+jquery), but it was from another [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619074/play-iframe-video-on-click-a-link-javascript) post.
If that doesn't help I found a [different post that seems to be more related to the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273984/typeerror-document-queryselector-is-null).