# Elements (buttons, textboxes etc) not longer working now they are inside a css tabbed tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I had a number of small tables with input elements, buttons etc in them and they all worked fine. I wanted to put them inside css tabs so that it was better to look at and they took up less room on the page.

I have all of that (css tabs using the divs) working properly now but I've now just realised that none of the buttons/textboxes inside the tables work anymore. They all look normal but don't do anything when clicked.

Any ideas? I've removed the code for the 3 other tables to make it shorter on here. In this example, it is the button called DeleteLibraryButton that does not work.

This is the link to the tabbed element: https://codepen.io/rafaelavlucas/pen/MLKGba

```js
// tabs

var tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks");
var tabContent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");

tabLinks.forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", openTabs);
});

function openTabs(el) {
    var btnTarget = el.currentTarget;
    var country = btnTarget.dataset.country;

    tabContent.forEach(function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("active");
    });

    tabLinks.forEach(function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("active");
    });

    document.querySelector("#" + country).classList.add("active");

    btnTarget.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 260px;
    margin: 0 5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .content {
        margin: 0 4%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
}

/* Tabs menu */
.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tabs {
        height: 40px;
    }
}

/* Tab Links */
.tablinks {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25%;
    /*change depending on the number of tabs*/
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tablinks {
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

.tablinks:before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #216aff 0%, #bd27ff 100%);
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}

/*tab buttons hover*/
.tablinks:hover::before {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tablinks:hover::before {
        height: 0;
    }
}

/* Tab active */
.tablinks.active {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 0;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    height: 110px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tablinks.active {
        height: 60px;
    }
}

.tablinks.active:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* Tabs text */
.tablinks.active p,
.tablinks.active:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.tablinks p {
    opacity: 0.6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #686868;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.tablinks:hover p {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tablinks:hover p {
        color: #686868;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
}

/* Tabs text bigger */
.tablinks p:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.1;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
    z-index: -1;
    font-weight: 600;
    top: 110%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tablinks p:before {
        display: none;
    }
}

.tablinks:hover p:before {
    opacity: 0.1;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: -80%;
}

/* tab content */
.wrapper_tabcontent {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: -3;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    top: 0;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    min-height: 180px;
}

@keyframes tabEffect {
    from {
        top: -40px;
    }

    to {
        top: 0px;
    }
}

.tabcontent.active {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    display: block;
}

/* Tab content line */
.wrapper_tabcontent:after {
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

/* Title */
.tabcontent h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 75px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    animation: city 1s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tabcontent h3 {
        top: 65px;
    }
}

@keyframes city {
    from {
        left: -150px;
    }

    to {
        left: -90px;
    }
}
/* Text*/
.tabcontent p {
    color: #686868;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 100;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    animation: fadeEffect 0.6s ease;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
    .tabcontent p {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Library Tabs Start -->
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Library Tabs -->
            <div class="tabs">
                <button class="tablinks active" data-country="CAL" onclick="return false;"><p data-title="CAL">Create a Library</p></button>
                <button class="tablinks" data-country="WEL" onclick="return false;"><p data-title="WEL">Add via WEL Code</p></button>
                <button class="tablinks" data-country="LA" onclick="return false;"><p data-title="LA">Library Access</p></button>
                <button class="tablinks" data-country="DAL" onclick="return false;"><p data-title="DAL">Delete a Library</p></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Delete a Library -->
            <div id="DAL" class="tabcontent">
                <h3>Delete a Library</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 200px">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button class="fancyDeleteButton" ID="DeleteLibraryButton" runat="server" OnClick="LCTDeleteButton_Click" Text="Delete Library ID:" />
                                &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="LibraryName" DataValueField="Id">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError document.querySelector(...) is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273984/typeerror-document-queryselector-is-null)

Comment: @TylerH are you making an educated guess?

Comment: @TylerH nope. Looks completely unrelated?

Comment: The events are firing. `country` doesn't provide an accessible `querySelector()` target. — And, what are you trying to *do* here: `document.querySelector("#" + country).classList.add("active");`, that's not already done here: `btnTarget.classList.add("active");`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles not 100% sure as it was copied code. The tabs are working and changing. It is the asp "DeleteLibraryButton" etc that is no longer working. Anything in the tables class="tabcontent" no longer works.

Comment: Other than the error thrown by `document.querySelector("#" + country).classList.add("active");` everything executes properly. — What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes, given that that's the error that appears in OP's code when that code is run, I made the educated guess that that might be the error OP is facing, and linked to it in a comment.

Comment: If that error is not something OP sees in their own environment, then their question does not currently contain a [mcve] and it should be updated to include one.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles When I put the tables containing buttons etc into the tabcontent none of them work. They get rendered but nothing is clickable. They worked before adding them to the divs and adding the css code to make the tabbed section. I just set up the divs from a template I found on the web and then copy and pasted the working tables inside them

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles. That the elements inside the tabbed divs such as buttons are still clickable and work.

Comment: @TimEdwards I don't know what happens when you say "work". Does something appear on the page? Is there some Javascript code you expect to execute? If so, what code? — The code in your question works as it is programmed. My guess is there is code you are trying to execute that is not within the functions you provide, particularly the function provided to `tabContent.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have all of that (css tabs using the divs) working properly now but I've now just realised that none of the buttons/textboxes inside the tables work anymore. They all look normal but don't do anything when clicked.

This line wont work:

```
    document.querySelector("#" + country).classList.add("active");
```

The elements cant be selected because they dont have ids.

I cant see any textboxes in your html code.

Comment: I took all of them out of my example to make it shorter and just kept 1 button and a dropdown list:

                                <asp:Button class="fancyDeleteButton" ID="DeleteLibraryButton" runat="server" OnClick="LCTDeleteButton_Click" Text="Delete Library ID:" />
                                &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="LibraryName" DataValueField="Id">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: They do have IDs. In the example, DAL links to DAL. The functionality of the tabbed divs does work. It is the stuff inside the tables that is no longer working. Sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: I see that you use webforms, it could be a server side problem. In webform there is a dependence in using the 'form' tag. Do you have the elements wrapped in that tag? what errors do you get when you click on the none working button (in the console)?

Comment: I'll have a look at the forms although it worked fine before when they were just in a table. I'm not getting any errors when clicking but might not be looking in the correct place. I am new to all of this.

I noticed that when I add a button or a hyperlink to the example (https://codepen.io/rafaelavlucas/pen/MLKGba) that I also can't click on them